# Vuejs - add property to each item in an array with reactivity

Tags: vuex, vue-reactivity

I have banged my head against all kinds of walls for days and would love some help with this please.

I am getting the following error but can't really see how what I'm doing has anything to do with vuex here:
`[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

In my vue component I define an empty array for future data I get from an external API.

```js
data() {
   return {
      costCentres: [],
   };
},
```

I have a watch on my vuex store object named `schedule` (which I've brought in using MapState... and also tried with a getter using MapGetter to see if that made any difference). In this watch I create my array costCentres, with each element consisting of about five properties from the API. I add two properties at this point (sections and tasks) which I intend to later populate, and which I need to be reactive so I do so in accordance with [the Vue reactivity documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) which all the other questions I've found remotely like mine seem to reference.

```js
watch: {
        schedule() {
            if (this.schedule.rows) {

                this.costCentres = this.schedule.rows.filter((row) => {
                    return row.cells[
                        this.schedule.columnKeysByName["Cost Code"]
                    ].value; // returns row if Cost Code value exists
                });

                this.costCentres.forEach((costCentre) => {
                    this.$set(costCentre, 'section', null);
                    this.$set(costCentre, 'task', null);
                });

            }
        },
```

**The `this.$set` lines throw the earlier mentioned error for every element in the array.**

When I later update the properties, the change is reactive so its just the flood of error messages that's got me beat. Obviously if I don't use `set` then I don't get reactivity.

I have no idea how what I am doing is related to the vuex store as `costCentre` is a plain old data property.

I've tried hundreds of variations to get this all work (including `this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })` which doesn't seem to work) and I've run out of options so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

(Please also let me know if I need to show more code - I was trying to keep this concise!)

Answer (score 2):

1. `this.schedule.rows` is an array containing some objects (mapped from Vuex so the array and objects inside "belongs" to Vuex)
2. You are creating `this.costCentres` by `filter` - so in the end `this.costCentres` is just another array **containing subset of objects** from `this.schedule.rows` (elements inside are just pointers to objects inside Vuex)
3. In the `forEach` loop, you are modifying objects which are part of the Vuex store and as a result getting error `[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

If you want to modify those objects, only way is to use [Vuex mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

Alternative solution is to make a copy of objects (create new objects with same values):

```js
this.costCentres = this.schedule.rows.filter((row) => {
    return row.cells[this.schedule.columnKeysByName["Cost Code"]].value;
  })
  .map((row) => ({...row, section: null, task: null }))
```

Note: code above creates just a shallow copy so if your objects does contain some deeply nested properties, you have to use some other way to clone them

Now objects inside `this.costCentres` are not part of the Vuex and can be modified freely without using mutations...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Your suggestion works perfectly, I can't express enough thanks! So that I'm clear for the future but, regarding your point (3), what is the object(s) in the Vuex store being modified in the forEach? I had thought `this.costCodes` was outside the store as a local data object and all I'm doing is updating it with two new properties?

Comment: (By not using map am I somehow linking `costCodes` to the store item `schedule`?)

Comment: If you put object into an array, the element in the array contains just a reference to the object (it's address in memory). If you then take this element and put it into another array (as you do with `filter`), it is still pointing to the same object in memory. 
https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0